# Determine if all needed header files are included in another header file

Tags: c++, c, header-files

Suppose I have a header file which should be including another header file but doesn't (for whatever reason). For example:

**myHeader.h**

```
#ifndef MYHEADER_H
#define MYHEADER_H

struct i
{
  uint32_t field; // Forgot to include <cstdint>
};

#endif
```

This mistake can be easily hidden in the .c/.cpp files. For instance like this:

**someFile.cpp**

```
#include "myOtherHeader.h" // <cstdint> gets included through this file
#include "myHeader.h"

struct i someStruct;
```

someFile.cpp will compile just fine and hide the fact that I missed including `cstdint` in myHeader.h. This isn't a problem here, but suppose when I want to use myHeader.h in some other .cpp file, that could cause a problem.

Is there a simple way to detect this omission of the header file? There are unpleasant ways, like manually looking over the file (but that is tedious and error prone), or creating a dummy .cpp file and including just the header file in question (but that isn't scalable to a large number of header files). Is there some static analysis tool or method that would check this for me?

Comment: Technically, you shouldn't rely on other files to include what you need. If you can avoid doing this, you wouldn't be asking this question

Comment: I sometimes use a technique where each header is included by its own little cpp file, that has no other code (or just some tests of the header functionality). That tends to find missing dependencies. And it's very easy to do.

Comment: @Smac89 I'm not relying on it. Many times I just forget to include the header file. I just get used to using a constant/function/type/etc. and have remember in enough other files that the one missing instance gets overlooked.

Comment: Oh, I see you're aware of the dummy cpp file technique. I wonder why you say that it isn't "scalable". After all every header is used somewhere.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I say it isn't scalable in the case where you're working on a large project with hundreds of header files, many of which include other header files and hundreds of other cpp files which include a wide range of header files. Call it header-file-spaghetti (like spaghetti code).

Answer (score 0):

You do it manually.

It's kind of silly to sit through and write code to check for you and paste it in every file when you can spend a 100th of that time just heading to the top and pasting the include statement in.

Comment: Ideally that's the way to do it, assuming you remember to. I know that I get in the habit of using uint32_t and sometimes treat it like a primitive in the language. Hence I forget I need to be including <cstdint>. But I've done it in enough other places that it gets hidden. Alternatively, if you work in a poorly designed/written legacy code base, as I do at work, the header files are sloppily organized and you can occasionally get a constant or something else "for free" without including the necessary header file because something else is covering it up.